# Migrate association column in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration, sql-scripts

I have a table that we've run into an issue because we made a wrong assumption that Table A associates with Table B but it should be Table C. It's only an issue now that we're adding a feature but I'm not sure how to properly migrate it.

Best way I can describe it is say you have an `account`, `vehicle`, `vehicleHistory`, `carLot`.

Currently `vehicleHistory` ties to `vehicle` but really `vehicleHistory` should be tied to `carLot`. Example tables. Here's what the table looks like today:

**account**

```
id  |
-----
001 |
002 |
003 |
```

**vehicle**

```
id   | accountId
----------------
101  | 001
102  | 002
103  | 003
```

**vehicleHistory**

```
id   | vehicleId
----------------
201  | 101
202  | 102
203  | 103
```

**carLot**

```
id   | accountId
----------------
301  | 001
302  | 002
303  | 003
```

But it should be like this:

**account**

```
id  |
-----
001 |
002 |
003 |
```

**vehicle**

```
id   | accountId
----------------
101  | 001
102  | 002
103  | 003
```

**vehicleHistory**

```
id   | carLotId
---------------
201  | 301
202  | 302
203  | 303
```

**carLot**

```
id   | accountId
----------------
301  | 001
302  | 002
303  | 003
```

Is this something I should even attempt in PSQL or should I just write a script in the app's language (Node or Scala)?

Comment: Do you have a way to find out which carlot.id should be referred by each vehicleHistory row? If you don't this can't be done

Comment: yea, it would be vehicleHistory is currently associated with vehicle which associates to account. From account you can get to carLot

Comment: sounds good, then this can be done. You don't have an sql fiddle by any chance? if not how about a few more rows for each so that it can be tried out

Comment: @e4c5 added more rows. I do not have a SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this very carefully in the database, but I think it can be done.  Basically, you want to replace `VehicleHistory` with:

```
select vh.id, cl.carlotid
from VehicleHistory vh left join
     Vehicle v
     on vh.vehicleid = v.id left join
     CarLot cl
     on v.accountid = cl.accountid;
```

My recommendation would be:

1. Run the above query and add additional columns.
2. Check to be very sure that this is what you really want.  Check for duplicate rows, mismatches, and whatever else you can think of.
3. Add a CarLotId to the `VehicleHistory` table.  See if anything breaks.
4. Populate the new column (see below).

To populate the new column:

```
update VehicleHistory
    set CarLotId = t.CarLotId
    from <temporary table based on above query> t
    where t.id = VehicleHistory.id;
```

From what you describe, there should be no reason to remove the original column.

Answer (score 0):

### (unchecked, since I don't have the DDL)

```
        -- to be safe: make a copy
CREATE TABLE vehicle_history_saved AS select * from vehicle_history;

        -- (maybe drop FK constraints here)
        -- do the update
UPDATE vehicle_history dst
SET vehicle_id = cl.carlot_id
FROM carlot cl
JOIN vehicle ve ON ve.account_id = cl.account_id
WHERE dst.vehicle_id = ve.id
        ;

ALTER TABLE vehicle_history RENAME vehicle_id TO carlot_id;
        -- (maybe recreate FK constraints here)
        -- (maybe drop copy )
-- DROP TABLE vehicle_history_saved;
```